# Has anyone else in the UK noticed WMC EPG information being retired by Microsoft in early May 2021?

Tags: windows-media-center

UPDATE (Later same day) Surprised (and a little embarrassed) to find my WMC guided data repopulating later in the day, in spite of the convincing MS-service cessation message, and a morning spent searching for info about it before posting the question below. I don't think it'll prove to be permananetly solved, so appreciate Tetsujin's comment advice.

ORIGINAL
While Microsoft's WMC EPG (Electronic Program Guide) service appears to have been switched off in the US some time ago (Jan 2020, according to MS), it only ceased working for me, under WIN7 and in the south of England, just this morning (May 12th 2021).

Has anyone else in the UK had the same experience, thereby confirming that this very likely is the official discontinuation in the UK, please? (Or might it just be a bug in my WMC?)

If the EPG has been discontinued in the UK, has anyone found a suitable replacement in the UK?

As always, advice appreciated. Thank you (in anticipation).

Comment: As there's no WMC in Win10 & Win7 has gone long past EoL, it's not really surprising. Google finds alternate sources, but I haven't tested them.

Comment: @Tetsujin, The surprise has been that I've still had the EPG till now, and, as updated above, it seems to have reappreared 'spontaneously' (I was setting a couple of recordings manually, so might have somethpw triggered a recall of some recent guide data). Also you're right about alternatives: https://digiex.net/threads/windows-media-center-tv-guide-data-fix-wmc-ota-epg.15262/ This one has good responses appended so it might work well in the UK.

Comment: I myself gave up and finally "cut the cord" after using WMC since XP.  Too many steps.. and I am too lazy.  I went to antenna only and use the Fire TV Recast which has free program data.  I know it doesn't solve your problem but thought that I would share.. I certainly miss my WMC.. but not the 80+ USD per month cable bill.. :(

Comment: Thanks for the hint. In the UK I'm lucky that it costs me nothing beyond my internet connection, which I need anyway, although we do have a separate Sky contract that doesn't link to my computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [EPG Collector](https://sourceforge.net/projects/epgcollector/) to download Freeview HD (DVB-T2) OTA EPG data. It can also upload this data directly into Windows Media Center.

I use Task Scheduler to run it twice a day (6:30am and 12:30pm). The latter one is to catch any last-minute changes to the evening schedule for that same day.

Comment: Just to clarify - its an alternative source?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Yes, it collects the guide data transmitted directly by the television channel within the television signal (OTA meaning “over the air”)

Comment: @Richard That could prove useful if/when my current EPG fades away; but for reasons I don't understand, I still seem to be getting the data in exactly the same way as for the last decade...

Comment: @iSeeker That's very strange as Microsoft pulled their online EPG service a couple of years ago. By that time I'd moved to EPG Collector because the HD channels didn't have any guide data. If your service ever dies and you need help setting up EPG Collector then give me a shout.

Comment: @Richard . Yes, I'm still puzzled about my good fortune in this respect. Legacy WIN7 machine (largely dedicated to WMC) and I'm unaware of any EPG-type transition that would explain why I'm still getting the EPG...